# Unit test for a function that transforms a PANDAS dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pandas

I am currently working on a project that uses many dataframe wrangling. The intention is to write test to check that the output functions are correct.

I have written a test for a dataframe function that transforms a dataframe of operations into another dataframe that contains the volumen of the operations for each of the containing days.

My question is:

#### Is this a good test for a function that receives a DataFrame and returns a DataFrame?

Should I do something different?

This is is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

class Operations:

    def disaggregate_ops_volume_date(self, df: DataFrame):
        """ Given a DataFrame with operations it generates an operation for each of the days it contains """

        if df.empty:
            return df

        ops = df.copy()

        ops['NDAYS'] = ops[['SEQ_PERIODSTART', 'SEQ_PERIODEND']].apply(
            lambda row: (row['SEQ_PERIODEND'] - row['SEQ_PERIODSTART']).days, axis=1)

        # Add a copy of each operation NDAYS times
        ops = ops.loc[np.repeat(ops.index, ops['NDAYS'])]

        # Correct the date based on the TradeId operation
        ops['SEQ_PERIODSTART'] += pd.to_timedelta(ops.groupby('TRADEID').cumcount(), unit='d')
        ops['SEQ_PERIODEND'] = ops['SEQ_PERIODSTART'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')

        ops = ops.reset_index(drop=True)

        return ops
```

#### This is the test I have developed:

```
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
import unittest
import pandas as pd


class TestOperations(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_minimal(self):
        """To make sure at least a test is passed"""
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_disaggregate_ops_volume_date(self):
        input = pd.DataFrame(
            {'SEQ_PERIODSTART': 
               ['2019-02-10', '2019-02-12', '2019-02-13'],
             'SEQ_PERIODEND': 
               ['2019-02-11', '2019-02-14', '2019-02-18'],
             'ID': [0, 1, 2]})

        input['SEQ_PERIODSTART'] = pd.to_datetime(input['SEQ_PERIODSTART'])
        input['SEQ_PERIODEND'] = pd.to_datetime(input['SEQ_PERIODEND'])

        expected = pd.DataFrame(
            {'SEQ_PERIODSTART':  
                 ['2019-02-10', '2019-02-12',                                                           '2019-02-13', '2019-02-13',                                              '2019-02-14', '2019-02-15',                                             '2019-02-16', '2019-02-17'],

              'SEQ_PERIODEND': 
                  ['2019-02-11',  '2019-02-13', 
                  '2019-02-14', '2019-02-14',                                               '2019-02-15', '2019-02-16',                                          '2019-02-17', '2019-02-18'],
               'ID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
               'NDAYS': [1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
                               })
        expected['SEQ_PERIODSTART'] = pd.to_datetime(expected['SEQ_PERIODSTART'])
        expected['SEQ_PERIODEND'] = pd.to_datetime(expected['SEQ_PERIODEND'])

        myops = Operations()

        assert_frame_equal(expected, myops.disaggregate_ops_volume_date(input))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test itself seems okay.

## bug

You use `"ID"` as columns name in the test, but `"TRADEID"` in the method to test.

And the result is not what was expected. The `TRADEID`s don't match

## Classes

There is no use for the class `Operations`. If you want to group functions that belong together, you can do so in a module (file) and import that. The fact `disaggregate_ops_volume_date` has a `self` parameter that is unused is a giveaway here

## Vectorize

there is no reason to calculate `ops['NDAYS']` row per row via apply. `(df["SEQ_PERIODEND"] - df["SEQ_PERIODSTART"]).dt.days` works just as well.

Then you can use `DataFrame.assign`, and don't have to explicitly make a copy of `df`

```
ndays = (df["SEQ_PERIODEND"] - df["SEQ_PERIODSTART"]).dt.days
ops = df.assign(NDAYS = ndays)
```

## Day

Since a days is used a lot in that method, it can be clearer to define that up front:

```
DAY = pd.Timedelta("1d")
```

`ndays` can then be defined as `ndays = (df["SEQ_PERIODEND"] - df["SEQ_PERIODSTART"]) // DAY`. Whether this is clearer than the `.dt.days` is a matter of taste.

correcting the date can then be expessed more clearly as:

```
ops["SEQ_PERIODSTART"] += ops.groupby("TRADEID").cumcount() * DAY
ops["SEQ_PERIODEND"] = ops["SEQ_PERIODSTART"] + DAY
```

## `input`

`input` is a `builtin`. By using that name as a variable name, you shadow that builtin. In this case this is not a big problem, but in general you should avoid this

## indentation style

You use a very inconsistent style of indenting the code, and what goes on a separate line. Better would be to remain consistent. For this, I use [black](https://github.com/ambv/black).

This changes:

```
expected = pd.DataFrame(
    {'SEQ_PERIODSTART':  
         ['2019-02-10', '2019-02-12',                                                           '2019-02-13', '2019-02-13',                                              '2019-02-14', '2019-02-15',                                             '2019-02-16', '2019-02-17'],

      'SEQ_PERIODEND': 
          ['2019-02-11',  '2019-02-13', 
          '2019-02-14', '2019-02-14',                                               '2019-02-15', '2019-02-16',                                          '2019-02-17', '2019-02-18'],
       'ID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       'NDAYS': [1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
                       })
```

to:

```
expected = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "SEQ_PERIODSTART": [
            "2019-02-10",
            "2019-02-12",
            "2019-02-13",
            "2019-02-13",
            "2019-02-14",
            "2019-02-15",
            "2019-02-16",
            "2019-02-17",
        ],
        "SEQ_PERIODEND": [
            "2019-02-11",
            "2019-02-13",
            "2019-02-14",
            "2019-02-14",
            "2019-02-15",
            "2019-02-16",
            "2019-02-17",
            "2019-02-18",
        ],
        "ID": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        "NDAYS": [1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    }
)
```

Which I think, is a lot more clear

## `pd.to_datetime`

You can invoke this immediately on a `list`, so defining the input DataFrame can become:

```
input_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "SEQ_PERIODSTART": pd.to_datetime(
            ["2019-02-10", "2019-02-12", "2019-02-13"]
        ),
        "SEQ_PERIODEND": pd.to_datetime(
            ["2019-02-11", "2019-02-14", "2019-02-18"]
        ),
        "ID": [0, 1, 2],
    }
)
```

## defining test DataFrames

Instead of invoking `pd.DataFrame` immediately, an alternative is working via a `csv`-like text input, and then use `pd.read_csv` and `StringIO` to convert it to a DataFrame.

```
expected_str = """
SEQ_PERIODSTART  SEQ_PERIODEND  TRADEID  NDAYS
2019-02-10       2019-02-11     0        1
2019-02-12       2019-02-13     1        2
2019-02-13       2019-02-14     2        2
2019-02-13       2019-02-14     3        5
2019-02-14       2019-02-15     4        5
2019-02-15       2019-02-16     5        5
2019-02-16       2019-02-17     6        5
2019-02-17       2019-02-18     7        5"""
expected = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(expected_str),
    sep="\s+",
    parse_dates=["SEQ_PERIODSTART", "SEQ_PERIODEND"],
)
```

Whether this is more clear than using `pd.DataFrame()` is a matter of taste. The advantage of this method is that it is easy to add or remove a line, and see whether the data is aligned correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I take note of all the information given. Alling is only a problem of copy/paste conde into the platform. I agree that reading a csv is a better way to perform the test.